# Module $\subset$ Field Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

In a recent assignment, my professor used the following notation which is giving me a bit of trouble. I hope someone can clarify. Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $K :=\text{Frac}(R)$, the field of fractions of $R$.  He writes,

$$ "\text{Let } M \subseteq K \text{ be a module over } R"$$

Of course, $K$ is a field and $M$ is an $R$-module, but it's difficult for me to see how, as different algebraic objects, one can be a subset of another. I'm not very familiar with modules yet, so I may be missing something obvious. Could someone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: It is also known as a *fractiona! ideal*. Don't forget that $K$ is an $R$-module, and, as such, it can have submodules. A simple example is the principal fractional ideal $R\,\dfrac1 a$ ($a\in R)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @Bernard!